# How to iterate ArrayList value using Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

This is my actual data in Subject bean

```
[
    {
        "subbat": [
            {
                "batn": "A1",
            },
            {
                "batn": "A2",
            }
        ],
        "id": "588edaf7adbe1d00013ff125"
    }

]
```

I want to rewrite this bean based on the subbat size I want to create like this and set one field "batn"

```
{
    "subbat": [
        {
            "batn": "A1",
        },
        {
            "batn": "A2",
        }
    ],
    "batn": "A1",                 -------//trying to set batn
    "id": "588edaf7adbe1d00013ff125"
},
{
    "subbat": [
        {
            "batn": "A1",
        },
        {
            "batn": "A2",
        }
    ],
    "batn": "A2",             -------//trying to set batn
    "id": "588edaf7adbe1d00013ff125"
},
```

]

But i got this output both -- batn = A2

```
{
    "subbat": [
        {
            "batn": "A1",
        },
        {
            "batn": "A2",
        }
    ],
    "batn": "A2",------------------------------->I got A2 here why?
    "id": "588edaf7adbe1d00013ff125"
},
{
    "subbat": [
        {
            "batn": "A1",
        },
        {
            "batn": "A2",
        }
    ],
    "batn": "A2",
    "id": "588edaf7adbe1d00013ff125"
},
```

]

This is my code for trying this what error in this code

```
List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
for (Subject eachSubject : subjectDatas) {
    if (eachSubject.getSubbat() != null && !eachSubject.getSubbat().isEmpty()) {
    for (Batch eachBatch : eachSubject.getSubbat()) {
        if (eachBatch.getBatn() != null) {
        eachSubject.setBatn(eachBatch.getBatn());
        subjects.add(eachSubject);
        }

    }
    } else {
    subjects.add(eachSubject);
    }
}
```

I used iterator way also but got same output is it logically incorrect

```
List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
ListIterator<Subject> iter = subjectDatas.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Subject eachSubject = iter.next();
    if (eachSubject.getSubbat() != null && !eachSubject.getSubbat().isEmpty()) {
    ListIterator<Batch> iter1 = eachSubject.getSubbat().listIterator();
    while (iter1.hasNext()) {
        Batch eachBatch = iter1.next();
        eachSubject.setBatn(eachBatch.getBatn());
        subjects.add(eachSubject);
    }
    } else {
    subjects.add(eachSubject);
    }
}
```

What changes made my code ?

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `subjectDatas`, please? (Naming note: "data" is already a plural noun.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Subject cloneable (deep clone) if it's not. Then you can use below in your inner loop.

```
Subject newSubject = eachSubject.clone();
Batch eachBatch = iter1.next();
newSubject.setBatn(eachBatch.getBatn());
subjects.add(newSubject);
```

Comment: i couldnt understannd

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with eachSubject object.
If you notice, your inner for loop is adding SAME outer object to the subjects list. Even though you set the correct value in first iteration of inner loop, that object gets modified in subsequent iteration...this will ultimately lead to adding same object n times and all the new subjects list's object will contain the last overridden value.
So don't modify the same object repeatedly, that should fix the duplication